# Event "fullscreenchange" doesn't work with version 4.6.1/4.6.2

Tags: video.js

I just found a fullscreen problem in the latest version of video.js (4.6.2).

Please see http://jsbin.com/nedudeqa/1/.

I attached a `fullscreenchange` event to the player, and the callback doesn't get called at all. (Failed in IE/Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera)

```
videojs('video').on('fullscreenchange', function() {
  console.log('fullscreenchange event fired!');
});
```

But this code works perfectly in the previous versions.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been confirmed as an issue that was introduced with the latest refactoring of fullscreen. You can track progress on the [open ticket](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1282) and downgrade if absolutely necessary, but I'd expect a patch out for this one fairly quick.

UPDATE: Just a note, 4.6.3 has been released and fixes this issue.